# Subscription Resets every night SSRS 2008 Standard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Report with multiple subscriptions. I have to send the reports on different schedules depending on the day of the week. I also have different sets of email address to send too. It seems that the second subscription will reset to run once a day after I have gone on and changed the schedule task in SSMS. This is my schedules

Mon - Thur 10am to Midnight
Report   send to Company1@CompanyAddress.com

Fri - Sun  10am to Midnight 
Report   Send Company1@CompanyAddress.com and Company2@CompanyAddress.com

These are 2 different subscriptions for the same report but the second subscription always resets itself back to run once a day and not daily between certain hours.

Thanks Dan

Comment: Does it throw any error ?

Comment: I get an warning in event viewer that A scheduled task in the SQL Server Agent queue has been modified or deleted.  event ID 115.